# Bounding largest real root of the sum of two polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, computational-mathematics, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two monic polynomials with real coefficients of the same degree $n$. Moreover, the roots of $f$ are $n$ consecutive integers that are known to us. Similarly, the roots of $g$ are also $n$ consecutive integers that are known to us. If we fix $\delta \in (0,1]$, is there a nice upper bound in terms of the roots and $\delta$ for the largest real root of the polynomial $h(x) = f(x) - (1-\delta)g(x)$?

If it helps, we can also assume that the roots of $f$ are given by $0,-1,\ldots,-(n-1)$ and $g(x) = f(x+c)$ where $c$ is some positive integer. So the roots of $g$ would be given by $-c,-c-1,\ldots,-c-(n-1)$.

(In the falling factorial notation, $f(x) = (x)_n$ and $g(x) = (x+c)_n$)

Comment: Do you know the falling factorial polynomials? The conditions mean $f(x)=(x+m_1)_n$ and $g(x)=(x+m_2)_n,$ for $m_i$ integers, where $(z)_n=z(z-1)\cdots (z-n+1)$ is the “falling factorial.” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've edited my post to include this notation, although I can't find any properties of the falling factorial polynomials that can help me answer this question.

Comment: Polynomials don't like to have equally spaced roots.  See [Wilkinson's polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial)  A tiny change to the coefficients makes a huge change in the roots.

Comment: Have you tried using bounds close to Stirling’s approximation to bound $f$ and $g$ and get a region beyond which it needs be positive?

Comment: I did try Stirling's approximation at some point, but it gives me a weak bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>n+c$, we have $f(x)>x^n$ and $g(x)<(x+c)^n$.

If we want $f(x)>d g(x)$, then it suffices for $x^n>d (x+c)^n$, so $x>d^{1/n}(x+c)$, so it suffices for $x>c/(1-d^{-1/n})$.

Letting $d=1-\delta$, for $x>max(n+c,c/(1-(1-\delta)^{-1/n}))$, we have that $x$ is not a root, giving a simple upper bound. You can get tighter bounds by being more careful about the factorials.

Comment: Thank you, that helps! Shouldn't it be $g(x) \leq (x+c+n-1)^n$ instead? It still gives rise to a similar bound. I also don't think the assumption $x > n+c$ is required, $x \geq 0$ should suffice.

Comment: Yeah, probably, you can fiddle with the details.